# css: how text-align, margins and padding work together

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble doing a simple quotation where the quotation is centered / floats on the page, and the person's name underneath the quote aligns to right side, as one often sees.

I tried changing the text-align of the person's name paragraph to "right", but that did not resolve it (it put it too far over to the right).  So, I left text-align alone (as "center") and then tried adding padding-left and margin-left, but both of those were ignored, leaving the person's name in the center.  **Can you tell me why these (padding and margin) are ignored**, and also a good way to do the alignment, such that the "whose-it-by" line matches up to the quote at the right-edge?

You can see the page here, with quotation at the top in the gray header area:  http://www.momentumnow.biz/mn/direct/testimonials2.shtml

I want to move the name over, but am curious why padding and margin don't seem to have an affect with text-align.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please note I fixed a few typos in question.

Comment: Just remember, there are tags especially for quotes - you should use those ... `blockquote` for longer, and `q` for short quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have two p elements means that they are displayed on separate lines - **p means paragraph**. Try placing one inside the other, or wrap both in a div, and apply absolute positioning. Alternatively, use my preferred method which is to change them to `span` tags.

Remember, `<p>` is a block-level element, whereas `span` is an inline element.

From what I understand, you want to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9KRjt/5/). Try using `float: right`

You could also use the CSS

```
p.yourclass {text-align: right}
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/TqE2x/

Comment: Hmm.  I want them to stack though, with one above the other, which block level elements will do.  Span elements don't stack, right? Also, please note they are both wrapped in a div.

Comment: It is unclear what you are aiming to achieve, please improve your answer of post a picture of want you want to I can give you some code!

Comment: Added picture.  Please see previous question -- i.e. I want them to stack, not be inline, so span doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Added float: right.  Doesn't work -- is too far over to the right.

Comment: I saw your latest jsfiddle.  I want the right-hand edges aligned.  Perhaps I'll try align-right for both and see how it looks.

Comment: That works, but so does just setting text-align="right" for the whole thing.  What I had before, was the "quote section" in the center of the page.  I still want that.   Then, inside, I want to get the alignment I described (i.e. matching right-edge margin).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks -- I matched it (I think), but the element doesn't float at all anymore.  Separately, do you know why padding/margin don't seem to have an effect with text-align set to center?

Comment: What do you want the padding to accomplish?

Comment: Well, before the quote/signature floated some as I expanded the browser.  Hence, if I could have just added padding to push the signature over to the right, it would have been ideal.   Perhaps I need to put a span in front of the signature, and set a padding or width on that span?

Comment: This is a much neater way of doing it, wrap it inside a div with position: absolute and set right: 0

Comment: On your page, apply this css to your wrapper div

Comment: Thanks man -- that looks good.  Please do me a favor and leave the jsfiddles, I want to experiment some more with your answers if I can.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem - they'll be there forever. They don't get deleted automatically

Comment: Please add the code to your answer.  Comments do often get deleted, and this was flagged as a long comment thread that should have been in chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve that directly only with CSS.

By using `text-align:center;` on the quote, you are not in control, how far the text will expand to the right side.

That's why you can't align the Person-Name directly underneath the right edge of the quote.

margin and padding will always work as you wold expect on `blocklevel-elements` and has some restrictions on ìnline-elements`. I don't know, what your problem was.

However, with Javascript you could append `&nbsp;` to the person-name, to match the same length of the quote and leave `text-align:center` on that paragraph. However you will run into trouble this way, if you quote has several lines.

Comment: Still working on it.   A paragraph is a block level element.  So, even if it has a text-align of center, shouldn't padding work on it, or margin?

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure why it had no effect for me.   I'm going to have to play with your jsfiddle and see what's different from my code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use CSS like this: p.caption { float:right } or {text-align:right} to move it to right side ; if it useless , may be some code is conflict.
2. If you want block elements to stack, you can use CSS [position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) (and [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)) property.

Answer (score 0):

You want the quote and the name to be in a single line or the name to be aligned-right with the quote?

This would bring the quote and the name on a single line--

change this css

```
p.headerCenter {
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
float: left;
}
```